# Replication of SQL server DB stops working due to continuous failure

Tags: sql-server

SQL server DB replication is marked as invalid due to continuous failure due to C drive spacing issue.

```
The subscription(s) have been marked inactive and must be reinitialized.
```

If we reinitialize, we need to be know about below items

1. How long will it take ?
2. And replication will be process from the start again ? or it will sync missed data alone ?

Comment: The first question is like asking "how long is a piece of string?" - we know *absolutely nothing* about your data, your hardware, your replication configuration... you haven't even mentioned what version of SQL Server you're using.

Comment: You have database and/or log files on your C: drive?